# Looking for a bathtub door

Tags: bathroom, toilet, bathtub

I'm looking for a stylish glass shower door. Which will be good between frameless and the framed sliding tub door?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought this one from amazon - Very chic! I love it! Delta Shower Doors SD3957014 Classic Semi-Frameless Contemporary Sliding Shower, 60" x 71", Chrome/Transition Glass

Comment: I checked details about Delta Shower Doors SD3957014. Yes, this model is awesome. Do you know about DreamLine Enigma sliding door? Here is a review:http://slickdoor.com/bathtub-door/